# HtmlWebpackPlugin but for generating handlebars/any type of template

Tags: express, webpack, handlebars.js, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to create a template that express can render with the Webpack bundles injected. I have this working if I remove `hash` from my outputs and reference the build bundles directly in my template but I would like to have Webpack generate my `entry.hbs` with the bundles added so I can leave my hashes in

The reason I want this is so I can make my React app scrape-able for OG data without having to deal with SSR.

**entry.hbs**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    {{#if isProduction}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{publicPath}}css/client.css">{{/if}}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script defer src="{{publicPath}}js/runtime.js"></script>
    <script defer src="{{publicPath}}js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script defer src="{{publicPath}}js/client.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```